# UK Immigration Officer stamped wrong and invalid date on Standard Visitor Visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

My friend, an Indian citizen and a resident of France, entered the UK via Calais on a new UK Standard Visitor Visa issued earlier in this month. The officer stamped the date as '32 NOV 2018' on his visa, when he entered just past midnight on 23rd of November. What are the potential consequences and what should they do to get it corrected?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is similar to [How to correct a passport stamp in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/121376/how-to-correct-a-passport-stamp-in-the-uk/121378#121378)

In my opinion it is not a big issue particularly because everyone knows nothing exists like 32nd November and furthermore it is in their database in which nothing like 32nd November can be coded.

He can get it corrected at an international airport or port of entry.

At Heathrow (and I assume for other ports of entry) a few years ago when my lost baggage was found, I was asked to return to the airport where there’s a telephone you can use to call immigration and they will come and get you and take you back into the immigration area where this mistake can be corrected.

You can also use **borderforcecomplaints@homeoffice.gov.uk** or **complaints@homeoffice.gov.uk** to contact them [like I did](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96671/can-a-uk-border-immigration-officer-remove-a-stop-indicator-flag/119574#119574) on a different matter. They do respond quite promptly.

[Complaints procedure](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/immigration-enforcement/about/complaints-procedure)

> Tell us as much information about yourself as you can. This will help
>   us to find the information relevant to your case, and to contact you
>   about it. The information you should provide is listed below:
>
> Your contact details. It is important you include your address and
>   phone number as we may contact you to resolve your complaint by phone
>   or to request further information
>
> the names of the applicant/ original complainant if you’re completing
>   this on behalf of someone else. We must have written authority to
>   disclose information about another person’s case
>
> full details of the matter you’re complaining about, including times,
>   dates and locations
>
> the names or identifying numbers of any staff you’ve dealt with
>
> details of any witnesses to the incident, if appropriate
>
> copies of the relevant letters or papers details of any reimbursement
>   issues including papers and receipts to support your claim

Comment: A suspicious officer may suspect the stamp, visa and passport to be fake, so I would not leave this be in a country like the UK TBH

Comment: @Coke Edited that part out of my answer.

Comment: Can't help wondering how many other people  had the same problem that night with Officer #xxxx?  The OP may find that there is a canned solution to this situation...

Comment: My friend contacted the UK BF by email, attaching the relevant pages of passport and tickets as proof of actual dates of arrival and departure. They replied in a letter, acknowledging the mistake and suggested that my friend present the letter and the invalid date stamp to an immigration officer on their next trip to the UK to have it rectified. This solves the problem, thanks!